# Why does Gson's toJson return null when using one-liner map

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson

Somehow `new Gson().toJson()` returns null when I give it an one-liner map:

```
Map map = new HashMap() {{ put("hei", "sann"); }};
new Gson().toJson(map);  // returns null!
```

All other implementations I can find works as expected:

```
new JSONObject(map).toString();             // returns {"hei":"sann"}
JsonOutput.toJson(map);                     // returns {"hei":"sann"}
new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(map); // returns {"hei":"sann"}
```

It works if I wrap the map:

```
new Gson().toJson(new HashMap(map));  // returns {"hei":"sann"}
```

A regular map works too:

```
map = new HashMap();
map.put("hei", "sann");
new Gson().toJson(map);  // returns {"hei":"sann"}
```

Is it a bug or a feature?

I've created a test project at https://github.com/henrik242/map2json

Relevant Gson issue: https://github.com/google/gson/issues/1080

Comment: Could you try with `Map<String, String>` ? I don't remember having issues with it but I never use `Map` without type

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1958961/4899193

Comment: Did you not read those github comments? Don't try to serialize  an anonymous inner class

Comment: @cricket_007 I did.  My point is that every other json serializer works.